# Iterate and grab nodes by position

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to copy the xml nodes in a repeating structure to another repeating structure by position...Meaning first node going to first first node and so on..

Help is greatly appreciated!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="error" match="XmlerrorItmOut/item" use="count(preceding-sibling::item) + 1"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Xmlitem/item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('error', position())/YyextError"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('error', position())/YyerrorDesc"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

First we create key. We use count preceding sibling nodes instead of position. Although it may be slow if you had thousands of item, it works.

The [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) copies every node "as-is".

The second template matches any `Xmlitem/item` element, copy it content and add error elements by key.